# Some windows always start minimized. How to prevent it?

Tags: plank, window-management, gala, minimize

When I open a certain types of windows they start minimized. Most annoying are the flatpak "open file with" dialog (openning an email attachment in Evolution from Flathub), or Steam in-home streaming.